# Why does the xor operator on two bytes produce an int?

Tags: java, casting, byte, numeric, xor

```
        //key & hash are both byte[]
        int leftPos = 0, rightPos = 31;
        while(leftPos < 16) {
            //possible loss of precision. required: byte, found: int
            key[leftPos] = hash[leftPos] ^ hash[rightPos];
            leftPos++;
            rightPos--;
        }
```

Why would a bitwise operation on two bytes in Java return an int? I know I could just cast it back to byte, but it seems silly.

Comment: For reference: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.6.2 and http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5233. I don't know the rationale, so I'm not posting an answer.

Comment: Seconded. I couldn't find anything describing *why* the above occurs, just that it does.

Comment: Type promotion exists for several reasons. For bitwise operations it would make much less sense than for nearly all others, but then - why not? You can always cast it back.

Comment: Because Java is already far too verbose for yet another needless cast.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because the language spec says so. It gives no reason, but I suspect that these are the most likely intentions:

- To have a small and simple set of rules to cover arithmetic operations involving all possible combinations of types
- To allow an efficient implementation - 32 bit integers are what CPUs use internally, and everything else requires conversions, explicit or implicit.

Comment: Using native 32bit CPU operations is the most likely reason.

Answer (score 5):

If it's correct and there are no value that can cause this loss of precision, in other words : "impossible loss of precision" the compiler should shut up ... and need to be corrected, and no cast should be added in this :

```
byte a = (byte) 0xDE; 
byte b = (byte) 0xAD;
byte r = (byte) ( a ^ b);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no Java bitwise operations on two bytes. Your code implicitly and silently converts those bytes to a larger integer type (`int`), and the result is of that type as well.

You may now question the sanity of leaving bitwise operations on bytes undefined.

Comment: Again, the question was *why* this happens.

Comment: That is why it happens, the question I think you're looking for is "Why did they decide to leave bitwise operators on the byte type undefined necessitating the implicit cast to int?"

Comment: The operations are *not* undefined; in fact they are defined quite clearly. It's just that the result is an int and cannot be stored in a byte[] without explicit casting.

Answer (score 0):

This was somewhere down in the answers to one of the similar questions that people have already pointed out:

http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/10/87247.aspx

Comment: None of those examples include a bitwise operator, which to my knowledge can not cause overflow/underflow.