# Java XOR over two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have to apply an xor over two arrays like let's say I have :

```
array_1: 1 0 1 0 1 1
array_2: 1 0 0 1 0 1
```

I would like to have a function that accepts two arrays and returns an array applying the XOR,
so in this case I would like this function to return:

```
returned_array: 0 0 1 1 1 0
```

Please help me with an algorithm .. Thanks !

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: This should help you => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726652/creating-a-logical-exclusive-or-operator-in-java

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having diffciulty with? It's not obvious what you need help with. I assume you don't want us to just write it for you.

Comment: A loop and for each element - pair make a xor. What is the problem?

Comment: I posted a solution, do you think it's good?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are storing these numbers in byte arrays, use this straightforward solution:

```
byte[] array_1 = new byte[] { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 };
byte[] array_2 = new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 };

byte[] array_3 = new byte[6];

int i = 0;
for (byte b : array_1)
    array_3[i] = b ^ array_2[i++];
```

**Output array:**

```
0 0 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: wow, what means b^array_2[i++]? b power array_2[1] ?

Comment: @user1843305 no. ^ is XOR operator in Java.

Comment: but the integer i doesn't increment does it? if it does that would mean that you do something like: b ^ array_2[1] and the i value becomes 1, so you're incrementing it and using it at the same time?

Comment: @user1843305 read and learn about array indexes and post-increment please.

Comment: `int i=5, j=5;
int a = i++;
int b = ++j;

i and j value: 6.
a value: 5 
b value: 6. `

Don't know how comes I didn't know about this .. Thanks

Comment: I get this compile error: "possible loss of precision      array_3[i] = b ^ array_2[i++]; required: byte found:    int, 1 error" anyone knows why?

Comment: cast to byte required. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003003/why-does-the-xor-operator-on-two-bytes-produce-an-int

Answer (score -3):

Would this be a good solution? (I wrote this thanks to what you gave me)

```
if(array1.length==array2.length){
  for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++){

    output.add(logicalXOR(array1.get(i),array2.get(i)))

  }
}
```

Of course array1,2 and output would be arrayLists

Comment: There is no logicalXOR() method in Java.