# XOR of two hex strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var hex1 = "B1C85C061C98E713DEF0E2EDDDDB432738674C9F8962F09B75E943D55F9FB39F";
var hex2 = "121B0D3327A21B8048FC7CA6FD07AACC0D8DF59B99DB098686696573E3686E6C";

var result = hex1 ^ hex2; //XOR the values

console.log(result); // outputs: 0 which does not sound good.
```

Any ideas how to perform XOR operations on hex values?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bitwise operations in JavaScript only work on numeric values.

You should `parseInt(hexString, 16)` your hex string before. Specifically in your case this wouldn't work because your hex is too big for a number. You would have to create your own customized XOR function.

Take a look at this link: [How to convert hex string into a bytes array, and a bytes array in the hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603205/how-to-convert-hex-string-into-a-bytes-array-and-a-bytes-array-in-the-hex-strin)

The resulting bytearray will be ellegible for a manual XOR. Byte by byte. Maybe this will help: [Java XOR over two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243922/java-xor-over-two-arrays).

Answer (score 9):

If you are on Nodejs, you could transform the hex strings to `Buffer`s then use `map` to build the resulting string.

```
function xor(hex1, hex2) {
  const buf1 = Buffer.from(hex1, 'hex');
  const buf2 = Buffer.from(hex2, 'hex');
  const bufResult = buf1.map((b, i) => b ^ buf2[i]);
  return bufResult.toString('hex');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
str = 'abc';
c = '';
key = 'K';
for(i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    c += String.fromCharCode(str[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(10) ^ key.charCodeAt(0).toString(10)); // XORing with letter 'K'
}
return c;
```

Output of string '**abc**':

```
"*)("
```

Comment: shouldn't `cli` be `str`?

Comment: Yes, you are right Tieme. I will change. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function like this.

```
function xor(a, b) {
  if (!Buffer.isBuffer(a)) a = new Buffer(a)
  if (!Buffer.isBuffer(b)) b = new Buffer(b)
  var res = []
  if (a.length > b.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
       res.push(a[i] ^ b[i])
    }
 } else {
 for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   res.push(a[i] ^ b[i])
   }
 }
 return new Buffer(res);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/czzarr/node-bitwise-xor

Answer (score 1):

Below is function that takes in 2 strings like "041234FFFFFFFFFF" and "0000000709000003" (a classic example of pin block and card block)
Expected result from the above 2 strings is "041234F8F6FFFFFC"

```
function bitwiseXorHexString(pinBlock1, pinBlock2) {
  var result = ''
  for (let index = 0; index < 16; index++) {
    const temp = (parseInt(pinBlock1.charAt(index), 16) ^ parseInt(pinBlock2.charAt(index), 16)).toString(16).toUpperCase()
    result += temp
  }
  return result
}
```

Note: This was made to xor 2 strings of fixed length 16. You may modify it as per your needs.