# How to xor my Strings using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am trying to XOR Two Strings. It's returning value with exponential notation, but in my case i need to pad the unmatched string with 0's.

```js
x1 = "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
x2 = "00000000000000000000000000000000011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
xor1 = parseInt(x1, 2);
xor2 = parseInt(x2, 2);
console.log(xor1, xor2);
```

Comment: Those numbers are too big for JavaScript to handle precisely. Consider using string functions instead.

Comment: Do it one character at a time and concatenate the result. Just write you own XOR for characters.  Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566421/xor-of-two-hex-strings-in-javascript for some ideas.

Comment: what does this have to do with angularjs?  Don't use a framework tag for a language question just because you use the framework in other parts of your app....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are parsing the string to binary numbers. `parseInt("0001100", 2)` is `0b001100`, or `12` in decimal. The numbers you're attempting to parse are **way** larger than [`MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), but that's kind of irrelevant anyway...

It's not possible to add leading zeroes to a number using xor, since the leading numbers are implicitly there anyway, so it won't change the representation of the number:

`(0b0000 ^ 0b100) === 0b100`, so `toString(2)`-ing that will leave you with `"100"`.

You'll need to go through your string character by character and build a string from it.

```js
let x =    "11000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
let mask = "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";

let result = mask.split("").reduceRight(function(partialResult, value, index) {
  if (index < x.length && x.charAt(x.length - index - 1) === "1") {
    return partialResult + "1";
  } else {
    return partialResult + "0";
  }
}, "");

console.log("Result is: " + result);
```