# Conversion of primitive types to int

Tags: java

While doing bitwise operation on primitive types smaller than `int` they are promoted to `int` and after operation they are converted back to their native type.

Why can't we simply do operation on native type?

Comment: Already asked in the site, somewhere to do with limiting the number of opcodes (instructions), search it if you are interested.

Comment: the answer is given here: [byte bitwise operations produce int][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003003/why-does-the-xor-operator-on-two-bytes-produce-an-int

Comment: first googled it but couldn't find answer. Thnx for link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common CPUs uses 32-bit number representation for that kind of arithmetical operations. That means that registers in the Arithmetic Logic Unit (ALU) of the CPU are most likely 32-bit and that's how CPU does it. It's obvious that implicit conversion happened.

Why Java does not convert it back to that "smaller" type, I have no clue. That's the question for creators of Java.