# Binary Ones Complement Operator (or binary negation) for booleans?

Tags: java, c, boolean

I will ask a rather simple question that was's a surprise to me.
I wanted to port a simple C code to java and in this code it used an `int` as `boolean`. Inside the code it inverted it several times like:

```
c = !c;
```

So naturally at first I thought a `boolean` will work fine. The invertion did not work though (using the *Binary Ones Complement Operator* ~).

I have tried `byte` also (after all I just needed a `boolean`) but the peculiar thing is that this code does not compile indicating an error `Type mismatch`:

```
byte c = 0;
c = ~c; //<= here is the error
```

The eclipse suggested solution was `c = (byte) ~c;` (conversion to `byte`).

So my question is whether there is a *Binary Ones Complement Operator* that operates on `boolean`s and `byte`s? Should it be overloaded for different types? I just want to invert the value of a boolean that shouldn't be too hard.

P.S.1 `long` works smoothly with ~ though.
P.S.2 I know how to work with `int` and then convert it to `boolean` but I thought a faster implementation should exist.

Comment: Java has the `!` logical not operator too. Just use that.

Comment: c is a different thing all together, if u r using c, you are using c, otherwise use what java defines

Comment: While this discussion is about xor, it applies to bitwise operators in general:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003003/why-does-the-xor-operator-on-two-bytes-produce-an-int

Comment: The reason `long` works without an additional cast is that `~` applied to a `long` produces a `long`, while `~` applied to a `byte` produces an `int`.

Comment: @Brett Okken, that was also a useful link.

Comment: There is no such thing as the "binary one's complement operator". `~` is the _bitwise complement_ operator. Whether the result can be interpreted as one's complement, or two's complement, or something else, has nothing to do with that operator. Anyway, it is not what you need for this task.

Comment: Also, Eclipse is an IDE. It will not make suggestions about how to change the contents your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `boolean` in Java and negate it with `!`.