# Bitwise operations in Java using byte and int

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, primitive-types

I'm trying to do some bitwise operations in java

I have 2 arrays:

```
byte[] bitArray;
final  byte [] bitMask = {1,2,4,8,16,32,64,-128};
```

then I try to `|` one byte in the `bitArray` with one byte in the `mask`.

```
bitArray[i] = bitArray[i] | bitMask[j]
```

The Problem is that I'm getting a compiler error.

"error possible loss of precision"
required byte
found int

The question is how can I fix it?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how to solve the problem

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003003/why-does-the-xor-operator-on-two-bytes-produce-an-int?rq=1

Answer (score 12):

What is occurring here is [*binary numeric promotion*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).  Java will promote the types of the operands for most binary operators, including the bitwise-or `|` operator, to at least `int` before performing the operation.  The result of `bitArray[i] | bitMask[j]` is an `int`, not a `byte`.

You must explicitly cast it back to a `byte` after the operation is done.

```
bitArray[i] = (byte) (bitArray[i] | bitMask[j]);
```

Also, using the [compound operator `|=`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) means you don't have to cast back to `byte`.

```
bitArray[i] |= bitMask[j];
```