# Is there any provision of Unsigned byte in Java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, type-conversion, bitwise-xor

When I XOR a byte lets say -1(in byte) with 2(int) I get -3 as a result whereas I want the operation to give me a positive int. This is due to the 2's complement representation and type promotion. I want to know if there a way I can use unsigned byte in java.

```
int x = 2;
byte y = -1;
System.out.println(x^y);
```

Output

```
-3
```

I found two excellent similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266756/can-we-make-unsigned-byte-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003003/why-does-the-xor-operator-on-two-bytes-produce-an-int). But I want some method or bitwise operation to return an int which can be later converted into byte without 2's complement representation.

Comment: The sign-extension of `y` doesn't really matter by itself, the low 8 bits of the result are still what you want, so if you're going to convert back to byte anyway it will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

All types except `char` (and `boolean`) are signed.

To get an *unsigned*-equivalent value, you can use a wider type and use a mask:

```
public static int unsigned(byte value) {
    return value & 0xff;
}

public static int unsigned(short value) {
    return value & 0xffff;
}

public static long unsigned(int value) {
    return value & 0xffffffffl;
}
```

Since Java 8, the standard API provides methods for that (e.g. [`Byte.toUnsignedInt(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt-byte-)).

Answer (score 0):

The only unsigned type in Java is a `char`, which is a 16 bit unsigned integer.

You could make use of that.

Mask away the more significant bytes using `& 0xff` if you need to.